# Node.js Heap Overflow error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, stack-trace, heap-memory

I am getting this error on AWS EC2 after 1-2 days of running this code

ERROR

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
st[10805:0x41cdff0]  7130379 ms: Mark-sweep 33.2 (78.7) -> 21.1 (75.8) MB, 13.8 / 0.1 ms  (+ 23.1 ms in 23 steps since start of marking, biggest step 4.3 ms, walltime since start of marking 160 ms) final$

<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: Scavenger: promoting marked
Allocation failed - process out of memory
1: node::Abort() [node]
2: 0x12b288c [node]
3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
5: 0xa96bfb [node]
6: void v8::internal::ScavengingVisitor<(v8::internal::MarksHandling)0, 
(v8::internal::PromotionMode)0, (v8::internal::LoggingAndProfiling)1>::EvacuateObject<(v8::internal::ScavengingVisitor<(v8::intern$
 7: v8::internal::Scavenger::ScavengeObject(v8::internal::HeapObject**, v8::internal::HeapObject*) [node]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::IteratePromotedObjectPointers(v8::internal::HeapObject*, unsigned char*, unsigned char*, bool, void (*)(v8::internal::HeapObject**, v8::internal::HeapObject*)) [node]
 9: void v8::internal::BodyDescriptorBase::IterateBodyImpl<v8::internal::ObjectVisitor>(v8::internal::HeapObject*, int, int, v8::internal::ObjectVisitor*) [node]
10: void v8::internal::BodyDescriptorApply<v8::internal::CallIterateBody, void, v8::internal::HeapObject*, int, v8::internal::ObjectVisitor*>(v8::internal::InstanceType, v8::internal::HeapObject*, int, v$
11: v8::internal::Heap::DoScavenge(v8::internal::ObjectVisitor*, unsigned char*, v8::internal::PromotionMode) [node]
12: v8::internal::Heap::Scavenge() [node]
13: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
14: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, char const*, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
15: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
16: v8::internal::Factory::NewStringFromUtf8(v8::internal::Vector<char const>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
17: v8::String::NewFromUtf8(v8::Isolate*, char const*, v8::String::NewStringType, int) [node]
18: node::StringBytes::Encode(v8::Isolate*, char const*, unsigned long, node::encoding) [node]
19: void node::Buffer::StringSlice<(node::encoding)1>(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [node]
20: 0x33c699f18dcf
```

My Main function is a async while loop which looks like this, this is a controller function for an express route

```
function controller(cb) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let killed = false;
    (async() => {
      let isEmpty = false;
      while (!killed && !isEmpty) {
        const code = await processBatch();
        if (code === EMPTY_QUEUE) {
          isEmpty = true;
          console.log('ss');
          resolve(false);
        }
      }
    })();
    cb()
      .then((state) => killed = state);
  });
}
```

Here, `processBatch()` can take around 10 sec to resolve the promise

NOTE: `processBatch` will never return `EMPTY_QUEUE` and killed is never set to true by callback

Taking this into account, can someone please tell me why this controller function is consuming so much memory after some time, am i doing something which is stopping node to garbage collect data or something like that ?

-- **UPDATE** --

this is the router code which calls controller function, and ensures no more than one controller is working at a time

```
const query = require('../controllers/fetchContent').query;
const controller = require('../../storage/controllers/index').controller;

let isFetching = false;
let killed = false;

function killSwitch () {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     setInterval(() => {
        if(killed) {
            resolve(killed);
        }
    }, 10000);
 })
}
module.exports = (app) => {
 app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.json({"statusCode" : 200, "body" : "Hey"})
});
 app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    if(!killed) {
        if (!isFetching) {
            isFetching = true;
            controller(killSwitch)
                    .then((response) => {
                        isFetching = response.isFetching;
                    });
            res.send({
                success: true,
                message: 'Okay I will extract send the contents to the database'
            })
        } else {
            res.send({
                success: true,
                message: 'Already Fetching'
            })
        }
    } else {
        res.send({
            success: false,
            message: 'In killed State, start to continue'
        })
    }
});
 app.post('/kill', (req, res) => {
    killed = true;
    isFetching = false;
    res.send(200, 'Okay I have stopped the fetcher process')
});
 app.post('/alive', (req, res) => {
    killed = false;
    res.send({
        success: true,
        message: 'Now New req to / will be entertained'
    })
 });
  app.post('/api/fetch', query);
};
```

-- **UPDATE 2** --

this, is the `processBatch()` function, it's role is to get data from Amazon SQS and after processing that data send it to another Amazon SQS and notify subscribers via Amazon SNS.

```
async function processBatch() {
let data = await getDataFromQueue();// Wait for the promise returned after messages are retrieved from the Queue.
let listOfReceipt = [];
if (q.length() > 50 ) {
  // if queue length is more than 50 then wait for queue to process previous data ( done in order to put a max cap on queue size )   
    await sleep(400);
    console.log(q.length());
    return CLEAN_EXIT;
}
//Also get the ReceiptHandles for those messages. (To be used for deletion later on)

if (!data.Messages || !data.Messages.length) {
    pushSNS(null, true);
    pushDelete(null, true);
    return EMPTY_QUEUE;
}
try {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.Messages.length; i++) {
        data.Messages[i].Body = JSON.parse(data.Messages[i].Body);
        const URL = data.Messages[i].Body.url;
        const identifier = data.Messages[i].Body.identifier;
        listOfReceipt.push(data.Messages[i].ReceiptHandle);// get the ReceiptHandle out of the message.
        q.push(URL, async (err, html) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                await sendDataToQueue({url: URL, content: html, identifier});
                pushDelete(data.Messages[i].ReceiptHandle);
                pushSNS();
            }
        });
    }
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    pushSNS(null, true);
    pushDelete(null, true);
    return CLEAN_EXIT;
// simply ignore any error and delete that msg
 }
 return CLEAN_EXIT;
}
```

Here `q` is Async.queue and it's worker function's i.e `extractContent` role is to fetch the content of provided URL.

There are the helper function for this module.

```
const q = async.queue((URL, cb) => {
extractContent(URL, array)
        .then((html) => {
            cb(null,html);
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            cb(e);
        })
 }, concurrency);


function internalQueue(cb) {
    let arr = [];
    return function (message, flag) {
       arr.push(message);
       if(arr.length >= 10 || flag) {
          arr = [];
          cb();
       }
    }
}

function sleep (delay) {
 return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), delay)
  })
}
// this is done in order to do things in a batch, this reduces cost
let pushSNS = internalQueue(sendDataToSNS);
let pushDelete = internalQueue(deleteDataFromSQS);
```

Comment: Could you please correct indentation in the code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your `controller` function returns a Promise which never resolves according to your statement that *processBatch will never return EMPTY_QUEUE*. I assume that you store returned Promises somewhere and each of them consumes memory.

Also each time you call `controller` function, it creates a new loop that calls `processBatch` infinitely. So if `controller` *is a controller function for an express route*, then each time someone requests that route, you create a new loop that infinitely calls `processBatch`. I bet that this is not a desired behavior and it definitely blocks lots of memory.

**Updated due to new details:**

Currently if someone will POST on */kill* and then POST on '/alive' without a delay, she will be able to POST on */* and start another loop in `controller` because `processBatch` *can take around 10 sec to resolve the promise*. This way if someone will make several repetitive POSTs to */kill* -> */alive* -> */*, she will effectively [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) your app. Probably this is what happening.

**Another update**

This code `q.push(URL, async (err, html) => {` starts a new query and attaches a callback that should be called after the query is fulfilled. The `q` counter decreases before the callback is called. But the callback is asynchronous (`async`) and it does another query `await sendDataToQueue({url: URL, content: html, identifier});`.

As you can see if `sendDataToQueue` executes slower than `q`, then callbacks accumulate and consume memory.

Comment: NO, this is why Killed is here, let me share what i am doing with router to put lock on routes. and may be then you can help me a bit more.

Comment: There is no way someone could guess that!

Comment: True this is a vulnerability in the system, but seeing the logs i can say with 100% surety /kill was never invoked nether was /alive. so this can't be the reason.

Comment: Can we take a look at `processBatch`?

Comment: But, will we ever have so many callbacks at one time, that it will explode full 1.5gb of node's allocated heap memory ? since these callbacks also resolves within ms ? and why would this happen after 1-2 days of running this whole system ?

Comment: As I explained in the answer, `if (q.length() > 50 ) {` does not work properly because `q.length()` decreases before your callback with `sendDataToQueue({url: URL, content: html, identifier})` finishes. So if for some reason the service that you send data to halts for several seconds, lots of callbacks will be created and they all will consume memory. I do not know how fast this service can accept data, but if it lags from time to time, then if is quite possible that you have a lot of callbacks hanging from time to time.

Comment: You can verify my assumption in a very simple manner: define a counter variable in the node module in which `processBatch` is located, increase it before `sendDataToQueue` and decrease after it. Also print it to console somewhere, for example in the beginning of `processBatch`. This way you will see how many callbacks are hanging in memory.